# Using a variable to create numpy array of particular size

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, datetime

I am trying to create an array where I pre-determine the end point of the array which is stored as a variable and passed to the command which creates the array. My code looks like such:

```
start = datetime.datetime.strptime("10-02-2007", "%d-%m-%Y")
end = datetime.datetime.strptime("29-04-2007", "%d-%m-%Y")
date_generated = [start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (end-start).days)]

number_of_days = end - start
number_of_days = str(number_of_days)
number_of_days = number_of_days[:2]
number_of_days = int(number_of_days)
print(number_of_days)

date_array = np.array(1,number_of_days)

for date in date_generated:
    date_string = date.strftime("%d%m%Y")
    for path_name in date_string:
        x = path_start + date_string + file
        date_list.append(x)
```

From this I receive the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-6ee54291c525> in <module>()
      9 print(number_of_days)
     10 
---> 11 date_array = np.array(1,number_of_days)
     12 
     13 for date in date_generated:

TypeError: data type not understood
```

I've checked and np.array takes integers as inputs so I am not sure why this throws an error.

Any help would be great.

Cheers,
Sandy

Comment: `np.array` with one integer will create a 0 dimensional array containing that integer which in most part an integer than an array but the second argument is supposed to be the array datatype which in this case you're passing an integer object. If you want to create an empty array there are already specific functions for that task like `np.empty`.

Comment: Ahh, yes. Silly mistake. Cheers though!

Answer (score 0):

You have mischanged

```
np.array
```

for

```
np.arange
```

Try this:

```
date_array = np.arange(1,number_of_days)
```